# Pusher implementation for android version>=21

Tags: android, pusher

While subscribing to private channel in a Pusher implementation for android version >=21, I always get the Authentication error as :

```
[com.pusher.client.AuthorizationFailureException: {"auth":"f1cec20bd1a33b264fe5:ef7d8eaf6b0199fb09c402a762b84aa5f7bd81ea1ab092a9d22223545823646b"}]
```

However for public channel pusher is successfully subscribed. Any help on this.